# Program in Fortran print different results with each execution

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This program prints different values for the variable `ar` each time it is run. Nothing was changed in the code between runs.

```
      IMPLICIT REAL *8 (A-H,O-Z)

      PI = 0
      PI=4.D0*ATAN(1.D0)
      PRINT *, 'PI =', PI
    
      ar = 0
      ar = 243.90472242d0 * PI / 180d0
      PRINT *, 'ra in radians=', ra

      END
```

First time programming in Fortran. I'm compiling with gfortran on Ubuntu 18.04.6. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

I'm putting below the outputs obtained in terminal:

```
 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   1.0600151175395439E-023

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -2.0629687487667335E-113

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -3.8284964032531453E+030

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   3.1129032950886427E-197

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -1.9759068544432418E+296

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   6.9844978200929715E-043

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -5.1456199117269666E-069

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   8.9199956919604065E-293

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -4.2627025759448686E-296

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   6.6564214481535599E+085

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -4.9868560013955360E-189

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -2.6981838685313715E+176

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -6.8783573079901012E+290

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   2.5019209606350738E+051

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=   2.5043572241487943E+102

 PI =   3.1415926535897931     
 ra in radians=  -8.4319767436500338E+073
```

I expected to get something like:

PI = 3.1415926535897931

ra in radians= 4.256940467391832

Comment: Please do not use pictures for output, just copy and paste it as text if it consists of text. This is particularly important for error messages. Also, do not just randomly add tags for all versions of Fortran available. When adding any text, please follow the instructions displayed when adding the tag. They say that you should not do this in capital letters.

Comment: In Fortran, do *not ever* use any  `implicit` other than `implicit none`. Use `implicit none` only. This is very important. You are just mixing `ra` and `ar`. Using `implicit none` prevents this kind of typo error.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

PRINT *, 'ra in radians=', ra should be PRINT *, 'ra in radians=', ar
If I remember fortran Uninitialized variables may have random values.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in the comments. But this is really a case where one should vote to close the question as "caused by a typo" instead of answering. We have loads of questions with the same problem, they repeat over and over and could also be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава even though it was a typo, it is a great example, of “Implicit none” being worthwhile.